# How to set order for a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, order

I'm trying to integrate a slider custom post type into WordPress and I can't seem to set the order (orderby:ID, order:ASC) for that custom post type.

I've added the `supports => array('title','page-attributes'),` to the post type, but when I change the order attribute for a slide, it doesn't change it's order (neither on the back-end or on the front-end).

This is the functions.php (it also give this error: `Notice: Undefined index: post_type in .../functions.php on line 105`)

```
function set_custom_post_types_admin_order($wp_query) {
$post_type = $wp_query->query['post_type']; // line 105
    if ( $post_type == 'bxslider') {
      $wp_query->set('orderby', 'ID');
      $wp_query->set('order', 'ASC');
    }
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'set_custom_post_types_admin_order');
```

And this is the bxslider.php

```
<?php 

// Create Slider

function hostify_bxslider_template() {

    // Query Arguments
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'bxslider',
        'orderby' => 'ID',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    );  

    // The Query
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    // Check if the Query returns any posts
    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {

        // Start the Slider ?>
        <div id="slider">

            <?php
            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
                <div>
                    <div class="slide">

                    <?php // Check if there's a BxSlider h2 given and if so post it
                    if ( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'bxslide_metabox_h2', true) != '' ) { ?>
                        <h2><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'bxslide_metabox_h2', true); ?></h2>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php // Check if there's a BxSlider h1 given and if so post it
                    if ( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'bxslide_metabox_h1', true) != '' ) { ?>
                        <h1><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'bxslide_metabox_h1', true); ?></h1>
                    <?php } ?>

                    <?php // Check if there's a BxSlider paragraph given and if so post it
                    if ( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'bxslide_metabox_text', true) != '' ) { ?>
                        <p><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'bxslide_metabox_text', true); ?></p>
                    <?php }

                    // Check if there's a BxSlider button link or button name given and if so post it
                    if ( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'bxslide_metabox_link', true) != '' || get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'bxslide_metabox_name', true) != '' ) { ?>
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'bxslide_metabox_link', true) ); ?>" class="button2"><?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_id(), 'bxslide_metabox_name', true); ?></a>
                    <?php } ?>
                        <div class="clear"></div><br />
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php endwhile; } ?>
        </div>

        <?php 

    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
}

?>
```

P.S. The slider works just fine, I just can't change the order of the slides.

Comment: [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) is an action hook, not a filter hook; try `add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_function' );`  Also, `$query->query_vars['post_type']` looks to be where you'd find your `post_type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Pat said, pre_get_posts is action hook, it wont work that way. But you don't need to use pre_get_posts hook in functions.php.
Remove this functions and filter from functions file and use these arguments in you WP_Query. orderby instead of ID, use menu_order.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'bxslider',
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
);
```

Comment: Using 'menu_order' instead of "ID" solved the problem. Thanks to both of you.

Comment: FWIW, `add_action` is just a wrapper around `add_filter` (they both use the same underlying API), and both will work in this case - but you should still use `add_action` here ;)